# Is there an SDK to create Plugins for Foundry Magritte / Data Connection Agents?

Tags: palantir-foundry

Is there a public SDK to create Plugins for Foundry Magritte / Data Connection Agents for special Data Sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at the time of writing this answer Nov/2020 the answer is No. Please reach out to your internal support team and they may be able to help it.

If a public SDK for Magritte becomes available, I'll come back and edit this question for clarity.

Comment: The Plugins currently available are specific to the requirements from the respective customer.